# How to get the HTTP status code from an ApolloResponse?

Tags: android, kotlin, graphql, apollo-client

I'm using the Apollo Kotlin library to query a GraphQL endpoint and I would like to check if the status code is `206` to properly handle partial results.

How can I get the HTTP status code of a `ApolloResponse`?

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to handle HTTP status code in Apollo Kotlin

1. Using `response.executionContext[HttpInfo]?.statusCode` if the response is between `200..299`
2. `ApolloHttpException` is thrown for HTTP codes other than the above state. You can use `exception.statusCode` where exception is an ApolloHttpException

Answer (score 0):

You can check the `executionContext[HttpInfo]` of the `ApolloResponse` that contains the HTTP status code info:

```kotlin
response.executionContext[HttpInfo]?.statusCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_PARTIAL
```